# I can't change the h1

Tags: javascript, html

I can't find the error. This code should create a h1 and a button, and when the button is pressed he should change the h1 to be written arroz.
I don't know if the code is wrong or the IDE "WebCode" that I installed in Play Store that didn't recognize my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <title>Hello, World!</title>

</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="numerador">0</h1>

  <button id="pudim" onclick="clicou()">+1</button>

  

<script>

  var numer = window.document.getElementByTagName('h1');

  function clicou() {

    numer.innerText("arroz");

};

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

I were expecting to the h1 to change from 0 to "arroz"

Comment: `getElementByTagName` should be `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: Check your developer console; you have an error in your code.  `window.document.getElementByTagName is not a function"` And then keep in mind what `getElementsByTagName()` returns when handing that variable.

Comment: Also `[htmlElement].innerText()` is not a function. You may want to check over the documentation for [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) and [getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)